# Azure.Management.Consumption.Models

Tags: .net, azure, sdk

Is there a way to access Azure.Management.Consumption.Models just like you do when you access the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent?

When I execute the following code I do not see Azure.Management.Consumption is the list. Am I missing something?

```
var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
    .Configure()
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithDefaultSubscription();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, please refer to the following code

1. Install SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption`

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption -Version 3.0.2
```

2. [Create a service principal with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-create-for-rbac)

```
az login
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "" --role "<you can use  Billing Reader, Reader, Owner, or Contributor role>" --sdk-auth true
```

3. Code

```
private static string subscriptionId = "";
        private const int NumberOfItems = 100;
        public static async Task testCosAsync() {
            var cred = new CustomLoginCredentials();
            ConsumptionManagementClient client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(cred);
            Console.WriteLine(client.ApiVersion);
            client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
            
            Console.WriteLine("---------------1");
            var r = await client.UsageDetails.ListAsync(null,null,null,top: NumberOfItems);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------2");
            var results = r.ToList<UsageDetail>();

            foreach (var result in results) {
                Console.WriteLine("Name:" + result.Name);
            
            }



        }
    }

    class CustomLoginCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials {
        private static string tenantId = "";
        private static string clientId = "you sp app id";
        private static string cert = "your sp password";
        private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
        public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
        {
            var authenticationContext =
                new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/"+tenantId);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: cert);

            var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.azure.com/",
                clientCredential: credential).Result;

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
        }
        public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
            }

            if (AuthenticationToken == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Provider Cannot Be Null");
            }



            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);
          

           
            await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        }



    }
```

[image]

For  more details, please refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-consumption-api-overview

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/consumption/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption